# How can I connect Schedule 40 PVC to Type C pipe?

Tags: drainage, pvc, adapter

I need to extend some 4" PVC drainage pipe.  The problem I'm having is that the existing pipe is "Type C" ("tele-duct").  It has a slightly different outer diameter (4.350") than a typical PVC pipe (e.g. Schedule 40, 4.50").

I've only been able to find one possible "Type C to Schedule 40" adapter product, and it's from a wholesaler with a high minimum purchase.  Is there any way to wrap the existing pipe with some kind of sheathing to increase the outer diameter before cementing it to a "normal" Schedule 40 fitting?

Comment: Is digging out the existing drain pipe an option? Because what you have isn't drain pipe. It's conduit for wires.

Comment: @longneck:  No.  I mean, of course I could redo what already exists, but it's not worth the expense.  (It's probably at least 50 feet of pipe under my backyard.) Yes, I already asked myself, "why did the idiots who put this in use telephone conduit?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast iron has roughly the same O.D. as your Type C. You could use a shielded "no hub" connector for iron to PVC, such as the [Fernco 3000-44](https://Fernco%203000-44).

You could also go all bushcraft and stretch your Type C a bit. By heating it slowly and carefully you'll get it soft, then work a sphere or cylinder of the right size into it until it cools. You can then do a standard PVC coupler.